# react-redux passport-google react-router: success callback url redirects to '/' and redux state resets as page reloads

Tags: react-redux, react-router-v4, passport-google-oauth

I'm building a page, where a user is allowed to fill in a form, but in order to submit it, he has to login. I am only allowing Google Login (passport-google-oauth2). After filling the form, if he has to submit it, and is not logged in, a dialogue box appears, where he is asked to login by Google.

After a successful login, the the google callback route, in I am redirecting him to '/' (homepage) 
Callback route code

```
app.get('/auth/google/redirect',passport.authenticate('google'), 
(req,res,next)=>{
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

I am using react router to handle routing on client side

However, when he is redirected to '/' the page refreshes and my redux state resets. (My form data is stored in redux state and it becomes empty again).

Here are my 2 questions.
1) How can I redirect to a page after a successful login without the page refreshing (redux not losing it's state)

2) How can I know from which route I came from and redirect back to the same route? ie: if I called google login from '/form', then I should be redirected to '/form' and so on

Thanks in advancce!